# What are the differences between Enterprise and Consumer version of IBM Worklight?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Are there any differences feature-wise between the Enterprise and Consumer versions of IBM Worklight apart from licensing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enterprise edition is sold for using within an organization (B2E). The license is "per device".
The consumer edition is meant to be sold for B2C and is sold per app.
Besides the license distinction, they are identical. In fact, its the same binary installation for both.

Comment: per app you mean a single .war file right? if yes we can have multiple apps inside the same .war file under consumer edition? or only app within one .war is allowed?

Answer (score 2):

From the Info Center:

IBM Worklight Consumer Edition and IBM Worklight Enterprise Edition are identical programs that differ in license only

Answer (score -1):

From dev perspective they differ just in security features:
https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/getstart/c_wl_editions.html

Comment: Note you are referring to the *Developer edition* there. The Enterprise and Consumer editions that the OP referred to are identical.